# How can I do fast sort of big objects array, sime Best way? (100Mb size)

Tags: c#, sorting

So i have big class Home.
And i have `Home[] array = ....`
In Home is `string Fullname`
How can I sort it by Fullname?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you can just:

```
using System.Linq;
.
.
.
var sortedArray = array.OrderByDescending(x => x.Fullname);
//or 
sortedArray = array.OrderBy(x => x.Fullname);
```

Comment: So is it a faster way to sort?

Comment: I thinks its pretty fast, but if you have such a big size object, maybe you need clean it some first, and then sort?

Comment: @АвраамЛинкольн "Fast" vs "faster" is all relative and dependent on the dataset. The first step is to establish that the speed of sorting is actually a problem. If it isn't, then making it faster is irrelevant. If it is, you can begin to explore more efficient ways of sorting, or more likely, consider a more appropriate data structure.

Comment: Sorting speed does not depend on the size of each "item", but on the length of your list. Just the references get moved around, not your Homes themselves